# getExternalFilesDir .. doesn't seem to get deleted during uninstall

Tags: android

I'm using getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES); to store some data that my app needs.

I'm only testing from eclipse (or an exported .apk), and when I uninstall the app through Settings -> Apps the files are not getting deleted.

All the documentation and questions that I have found in StackOverflow seem to lead me to believe these files should be getting deleted during uninstall, but they still seem to exist.

Is this because it's not installed from the market? I'm targeting level 10

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing from the market does not seems to be the problem.

The behavior you explained is just like  getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() method works. Are you sure that you are not calling this method instead of getExternalFilesDir() ?

Take a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal , section "Saving files that should be shared"

I hope it helps

Comment: The method was copied directly out of my code so I know it must be the correct one.  I can't store the files internally because in the end the files could be up to 500 megs, and I'm more likely to blow the internal storage.  I also don't want to use the shared public because I would like the files to get deleted on uninstall.  thanks though.